# Vaadin 14 - Grid::setClassNameGenerator doesn't work

Tags: java, vaadin

I have a problem with setting a background color for each row in a grid. I use setClassNameGenerator, but this doesn't work. However, if I set the className for the whole grid, then I can see some result. In the end, I want to color the rows based on certain conditions, but for now I just hard-coded one class "failed" to see if coloring works.

---

Here is my CSS code:

[image: My CSS]

---

Execution of this snippet doesn't change anything

[image: No results when executing this snippet]

---

However, this makes the whole background yellow as expected, so the CSS import is ok.

[image: This works]

---

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Which version of vaadin are you using, and please show us how you import the css. Without this information, I'll just assume that [this](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18003166/18003266) will help you

Comment: Vaadin 14 as in the title, and I was importing the CSS in the wrong way as you said

Comment: Could you please replace the screenshots with the actual code? Screenshots are not searchable and a potential answer can not copy and improve on it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You say that your last code works "so the CSS import is ok" - No, it's not.

It's a huge difference because the row styles need to be defined inside the grid component's scope while setting the background of the whole grid can be done with global css. This is because `Grid` is using a shadow-DOM. You canread up on that [here](https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/themes-and-styling-in-vaadin#component-scope), or more extensively [here](https://github.com/vaadin/vaadin-themable-mixin#readme)

What you need to do in order to load your CSS into the scope of the grid component is add theparameter `themeFor = "vaadin-grid"` to the `@CssImport` annotation.

`@CssImport(value = "./styles/failedGridColumn.css", themeFor = "vaadin-grid")`
instead of
`@CssImport("./styles/failedGridColumn.css")`